# Noisy string matching in Java?

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, substring

Consider the following strings:

Arg = "north_carolina_state_university"

Text = "Hackney attended North Carolina State University before transferring to the University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, where he earned bachelor's and Juris Doctor degrees. He worked as a prosecutor from 1971-74 before going into private practice. In 1974, he was campaign manager for Congressman Ike Andrews. While an undergraduate at UNC-Chapel Hill, he wrote his Honors Thesis on the history of the North Carolina corrections system."

I know a variants of Arg could be found in the Text, but there are not necessarily the same, and the Arg could be noisy.

Another example is the following :

Arg2 = "maurice_blackburn"

Text2 = "Maurice McCrae Blackburn (19 November 1880 -- 31 March 1944), Australian politician and lawyer, was born in Inglewood, Victoria. He moved to Melbourne with his mother following the death of his father in 1887. He was educated at Melbourne Grammar School matriculating in 1896. After completing school, he attended the University of Melbourne, graduating in arts and law in 1909, and began to practice as a lawyer a year later."

In the above example the middle-name in the Arg2 is not used in the Text2.

Arg3 = "kansas_city_metropolitan_area"
Text3 = "Roach was elected as a Republican to the Sixty-seventh and Sixty-eighth Congresses (March 4, 1921-March 3, 1925). He served as chairman of the Committee on Expenditures in the Department of Justice (Sixty-eighth Congress). He was an unsuccessful candidate for reelection in 1924 to the Sixty-ninth Congress. He moved to St. Louis, Missouri, December 27, 1924, and resumed the practice of law. He died at Kansas City, Missouri, June 29, 1934. He was interred in Roach Cemetery near Roach, Missouri".

In this example "Kansas City" has appeared in the Text3, but without the "metropolitan area" (as it has appeared in the Arg3).

Any function/library to discover the occurrence of the Arg in the text?

Comment: You can probably use the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: What does "most likely" mean in your last sentence?

Comment: @CommuSoft: Know any library doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this answer can help you at least get some ideas. I created a method to answer this question

> Any function/library to discover the occurrence of the Arg in the text?

Here is the following output I receive from my method using your examples above:

> Arg = "north_carolina_state_university"
>
> Text = "Hackney attended North Carolina State University before
>   transferring to the University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, where
>   he earned bachelor's and Juris Doctor degrees. He worked as a
>   prosecutor from 1971-74 before going into private practice. In 1974,
>   he was campaign manager for Congressman Ike Andrews. While an
>   undergraduate at UNC-Chapel Hill, he wrote his Honors Thesis on the
>   history of the North Carolina corrections system."
>
> **Output**
>
> Match Results
>
> Words:4/4
>
> Letters:28/28
>
> ---
>
> Arg2 = "maurice_blackburn"
>
> Text2 = "Maurice McCrae Blackburn (19 November 1880 -- 31 March 1944),
>   Australian politician and lawyer, was born in Inglewood, Victoria. He
>   moved to Melbourne with his mother following the death of his father
>   in 1887. He was educated at Melbourne Grammar School matriculating in
>   1896. After completing school, he attended the University of Melbourne, graduating in arts and law in 1909, and began to practice
>   as a lawyer a year later."
>
> **Output**
>
> Match Results
>
> Words:2/2
>
> Letters:16/16
>
> ---
>
> Arg3 = "kansas_city_metropolitan_area"
>
> Text3 = "Roach was elected as a
>   Republican to the Sixty-seventh and Sixty-eighth Congresses (March 4,
>   1921-March 3, 1925). He served as chairman of the Committee on
>   Expenditures in the Department of Justice (Sixty-eighth Congress). He
>   was an unsuccessful candidate for reelection in 1924 to the
>   Sixty-ninth Congress. He moved to St. Louis, Missouri, December 27,
>   1924, and resumed the practice of law. He died at Kansas City,
>   Missouri, June 29, 1934. He was interred in Roach Cemetery near Roach,
>   Missouri".
>
> **Output**
>
> Match Results
>
> Words:2/4
>
> Letters:13/26

This method searches only the English letter alphabet and only searches words(space delimited) it also does not search word lettering out of order. If you search cat and someone types acat it will show up as not a match nor will it show up as any letter match. This is intended because dog is not hotdog. You really have to decide how fuzzy you want your match to be. This code is by no means the best but I hope it can give you some ideas and maybe can rewrite it to be much more neat and orderly. Either way it does answer the exact question you asked.

```
public static String search(String search, String target) {
        String result = "";
        search = search.toLowerCase();
        target = target.toLowerCase();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<String> searchWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> targetWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        char lastChar = ' ';
        char currentChar = ' ';
        // search,text
        int swords, twords, sletters, tletters, mwords, mletters;
        swords = twords = sletters = tletters = mwords = mletters = 0;

        for (Character c : search.toCharArray()) {
        currentChar = c > 96 && c < 123 ? c : ' ';
        if (lastChar == ' ' && currentChar == ' ')
            continue;
        if (currentChar != ' ' && ++sletters != 0)
            temp.append(currentChar);
        else {
            searchWords.add(temp.toString());
            temp.setLength(0);
        }
        lastChar = currentChar;
        }
        searchWords.add(temp.toString());
        temp.setLength(0);
        lastChar = ' ';
        for (Character c : target.toCharArray()) {
        currentChar = c > 96 && c < 123 ? c : ' ';
        if (lastChar == ' ' && currentChar == ' ')
            continue;
        if (currentChar != ' ' && ++tletters != 0)
            temp.append(currentChar);
        else {
            targetWords.add(temp.toString());
            temp.setLength(0);
        }
        lastChar = currentChar;
        }
        targetWords.add(temp.toString());
        temp.setLength(0);
        search = searchWords.toString();
        target = targetWords.toString();
        swords = searchWords.size();
        twords = targetWords.size();
        int[] blm = new int[searchWords.size()]; // best letter match
        int lm = 0;// letter match
        for (int i = 0; i < searchWords.size(); i++) {
        for (String t : targetWords) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < (searchWords.get(i).length() < t
                .length() ? searchWords.get(i).length() : t
                .length()); i2++) {
            if (t.charAt(i2) == searchWords.get(i).charAt(i2))
                lm++;
            }
            if (blm[i] < lm)
            blm[i] = lm;
            lm = 0;
        }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < blm.length; i++) {
        if (blm[i] == searchWords.get(i).length())
            mwords++;
        mletters += blm[i];
        }

        result = MessageFormat
            .format("-----\nSearch text:\"{0}\"\nWords:{1}\nLetters:{2}\n-----\nTarget text:\"{3}\"\nWords:{4}\nLetters:{5}\n-----\nMatch Results\nWords:{6}/{1}\nLetters:{7}/{2}",
                search, swords, sletters, target, twords, tletters,
                mwords, mletters);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @Daniel Glad to help. If you have any questions about any of the code or anything further concerning this question please ask here so we can update/cleanup the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a standard search engine problem. If the query and the search strings are small, you need to tokenize the query and search string. Then search for the tokens in the increasing order in the Search String.

Search engines do the same and tokenization is a very hard problem. Not all languages use whitespace as delimiters. Chinese/Japanese will be a nightmare for tokenizers.

Comment: Agreed, let's limit ourselves to English. Do you know any library that I can use off the shelf?

Comment: @Daniel You want to find random words in large strings? Why not just check if the word occurs in the string? Is there something I am missing here.

Comment: @CodeCamper : It is not random. I know they appear in the text in some form, but its appearance might be a little different. See the examples in the main question.

Comment: @Daniel I read the original question, what do you consider to be variants? Do you consider a misspelling to be variants and do you consider hot to be hotdog?

Comment: @CodeCamper: It really depends on the context. It is usually in the level of a small misspelling.

Comment: @Daniel Do you just want it to return true or false? Do you want it to return partial matches? Do you want it to return a percentage or scale? For example searching for "Rock University" do you want "He went to Rock" to return true?

Comment: @CodeCamper: Partial matches(not yes/no). Also a percentage of match or number of characters would be very interesting. Yes, that'd makes to be a match.

Comment: @Daniel You said you wanted it to be English. To narrow the search did you want it to only be letters and disregard capitalization and punctuations?

Comment: @CodeCamper: Yes, only in English. And yes, ignoring capitalization and punctuation (e.g. "queen's college" is the same as "queens college").

Comment: I dont know of any library, but if your use case is simple use String.Split with your delimiters and canonicalize the tokens ( lower case) and search it. If you want fuzzy matches that is a really hard problem.

Comment: Look at Jaccard Index and Min Hashing. Just to let you know that this is not a weekend project. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index